# Link navigation button to open web link

Tags: ios, xcode-storyboard

I am looking to Link a navigation button through an app I am building via storyboard to an external website. I could link it to another controller and build a WEB Controller but i am looking to open a website directly from that button instead.

Comment: As you a beginner as I can see, I suggest you to look this video to understand how to create IBAction form storyboard https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_fIopL5tDgU

Answer (score 0):

You should add IBAction or segue to your view controller at first.

I suppose that the method will look like below:

```
- (IBAction)pressedWebButton
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.http://stackoverflow.com"]];
}
```